# android - How to detect speech

Tags: android, speech-recognition

In android is there a Api i can use to detect when the user speaks into the mic ?

So im expecting there is a voice recognition build into android or some speech to text api i can use to detect someone speaking, any ideas ? Can ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH help me?

Comment: Do you want to translate Voice to Text or you just want to know when your user is speaking?

Comment: I want to know when the user speaks into the phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it works is you create an `Intent` with `ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` and call `startActivityForResult()`.  Then in your `onActivityResult()` override, you can pull the speech-to-text data from the result `Intent` extras.

Here's a neat tutorial to get you started:

[Make your next Android app a good listener -- TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/make-your-next-android-app-a-good-listener/)

Comment: Does this solution require internet ?